# How do I create a file with a user-supplied name in C++?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I want the user to be able to type some text and then the computer creates a file called what ever the text was. In C++.

Comment: Is this for homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Comment: OK, so is this homework, or what?  What code do you have?  Where are you having trouble?  Do you know how to read input from a user?  Do you know how to write to a file?

Comment: Using the acronym 'ASAP' in your title really rubs people the wrong way.  We are not your personal answering service.  We will answer the question in our own time and your requests to have us give you a free answer to your question with all haste seem rather selfish and self-serving.  I edited the title to more accurately reflect the question so its no longer there.

Comment: SO works best if you have specific questions.  Write what you can, and either it will work or you'll have more specific questions to ask when you post your attempt.

Comment: What OS is this for? Different OSes have different file name restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    return system("read FILE && touch \"$FILE\"");
}
```

Note: Requires POSIX. Should be OK, practically all modern OSes are POSIX-compatible.

Comment: +1, does satisfy user requirements

Answer (score 1):

Because this looks like homework, I'm not giving a complete example.

Look in:

- `#include <iostream>` (Preferred) or
- `#include <cstdio>` (Legacy)